# We can't add a primitive type value to a ArrayList<Integer> right?? Why is this code working ?? (arrayList should only contain only objects right? )

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

**We can't add a primitive type value to a ArrayList  right?? Why is this code working ?? (arrayList should only contain only objects right? )**

```
static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
        int aPoints = 0;
        int bPoints =0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            if(a.get(i)>b.get(i)){
                aPoints++;
            } else {
                if(a.get(i)<b.get(i)) {
                    bPoints++;
                } else {
                    if(a.get(i)==b.get(i)){
                        aPoints = aPoints + 0;
                        bPoints = bPoints + 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Integer>points = new ArrayList<>();
        points.add(aPoints);
        points.add(bPoints);
        return points;
    }
```

Comment: autoboxing is converting primitive type to its wrapper class, but in the above i just used the add keyword it worked .

Comment: That's what autoboxing is, it's autoboxed by compiler for you.

Comment: when i use  points.add(aPoints) , am i converting primitive dataType to an integer object ?

Comment: Not you, compiler is.

Comment: ok yeah i mean compiler , thanks a lot mr aniket :)